# Lua: Smartest way to add to table only if not already in table, or remove duplicates

Tags: lua

I have a table of strings. I'd like an easy way to remove all of the duplicates of the table.

So if the table is `{a, b, c, c, d, e, e}` , after this operation it would be `{a, b, c, d, e}`

Alternatively, and probably preferably, is there a way to add an element to a table, but only if it is not already contained within the table.

<\noobquestion>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I normally do for this is index the table on the string so for example

```
tbl[mystring1] = 1
tbl[mystring2] = 1
```

etc.

When you add a string you simply use the lines above and duplicates will be taken care of. You can then use a for  ... pairs do  loop to read the data.

If you want to count the number of occurrences

use something like

```
if tbl[mystring1] == nil then
  tbl[mystring1] = 1
else
  tbl[mystring1] = tbl[mystring1] + 1
end
```

As the end of the addition cycle if you need to turn the table around you can simply use something like

```
newtbl = {}
for s,c in pairs(tbl) do
  table.insert(newtbl,s)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you're trying to implement a Set, a collection of unique elements. This article might help you: http://www.lua.org/pil/13.1.html

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is using the tables as keys, not as values, in your "container table".

Let's call the container table `values`. You must currently be doing something similar to this for adding elements to it:

```
table.insert(values, value)
```

And you parse `values` like this:

```
for i,v in ipairs(values) do
  -- v contains the internal values
end
```

In order to have the tables just once, you can insert them this other way:

```
values[value] = 1
```

This will ensure that the inserted values (strings, tables, numbers, whatever) are included just once, because they will be 'overwritten'.

Then you can parse `values` like this:

```
for k,_ in pairs(values) do
  -- k contains the internal tables
end
```